# Create PostgreSQL DB On Connection

Tags: postgresql

I want to reduce the number of requirements to get started with my webapp. At the moment you need to run a "create database, create user, grant all" script before you can start debugging.

I'd like the code to be checked out and run straight away without requiring developers to have to read through lots of documentation and do lots of manual steps.

h2 allows you to specify a connection string and it will create the db if it doesn't already exist.

Is it possible to do that using PostgreSQL?

Or is my only option (to meet the requirements) to configure h2 for dev work and PostgreSQL for production?

Comment: "*Code to be checked out and run straight away*" simply doesn't work with a server based database. You will always need to install that DB server first. And creating a database and the user is a relatively small step compared to installing the  DBMS server. So the answer: no, this is not possible with Postgres. You will have to use an embedded DBMS if you really want that

Answer (score 0):

A connection in Postgres is always to a particular database, but by default every install will have a `postgres` DB intended for running maintenance commands. The user will still need to supply some superuser login credentials, but assuming you have those, you can run your "create database, create user, grant all" script automatically when the webapp is first accessed.

For instance, have a generated config file which is ignored in source control; before loading the file, check if it exists; if it doesn't, run the install routine.

You can even load an HTML form allowing the user to provide the superuser credentials, choose a name for the DB, and any other commonly-changed configuration options. If these are all defaulted, the "manual step" is simply to glance that they are correct, and click "OK".